# Laravel websockets causes python socket error

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, websocket, supervisord

I got a project installed in ubuntu 18.04 using amazon ec2. I can manually test the websocket server running by `websockets:serve` command from my project directory. Now that I want to run websockets, the [docs](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/1.0/basic-usage/starting.html#keeping-the-socket-server-running-with-supervisord) said that I need to install `supervisor` and thats what I did. I created a config file in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/websockets.conf` and it has this configuration

```
[program:websockets]
command=usr/bin/php cd /var/www/html/Inventory/artisan websockets:serve
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=laravel-echo
```

when I do `supervisorctl update`, what I got is

`error: <class 'socket.error'>, [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file: /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py line: 228`

and when i also do `sudo supervisorctl status` what I get is

`unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock no such file`

I dont have a `supervisor.conf` in my `/etc` directory, the `supervisor.conf` file is in `/etc/supervisor/supervisor.conf` just like others encountered.

Do i need to create a `supervisor.sock` file? or supervisor will create it automatically? Also, my second resort if I cant solve this problem is running websockets by a cronjob. Is that the right thing to do?

Anyways, if you guys got an idea about this please help. Thanks..

Comment: check this https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/1.0/basic-usage/starting.html#keeping-the-socket-server-running-with-supervisord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the "cd" from command

```
[program:websockets]
command=/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/Inventory/artisan websockets:serve
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=laravel-echo
```

You can find some refences [here](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/1.0/basic-usage/starting.html#keeping-the-socket-server-running-with-supervisord)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213903/discussion-on-answer-by-dilson-rainov-laravel-websockets-causes-python-socket-er).

Answer (score 1):

```
[program:laravel-websocket]
command=/path/to/your/php /var/www/vhosts/path/to/yout/artisan websockets:serve
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=your_user
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor-laravel.websocket.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor-laravel.websocket.out.log
```

Never run as root

Absolute paths, and of course follow supervisord config guide

Check error logs

Do a netcat/port scan on configured port to be sure you don't miss proxy/firewall rules

ref: https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/304#issuecomment-590809667

Comment: is my directory wrong for websockets:serve? i pointed it out in the correct directory

Comment: can you restart server?

Comment: i can run the websockets. its just the supervisor problem.

Comment: https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/480#issuecomment-52885443

Comment: if you restart it will start supervisor and run websockets from supervisor, then you check logs

Comment: glad you fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution of mine, I just used cron to run `websockets:serve` once a year.

```
51 16 9 5 * cd /var/www/html/Inventory/ && php artisan websockets:serve >> /dev/null 2>&1 >> /var/www/html/Inventory/websockets.log
```